# MS SQL identify duplicate rows based on log time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly simple database table that logs every time a tray passes over an RFID reader. What sometimes happens is the data is being sent twice, so I have been asked if I can find out how often this happens. Rather than spending the next few days going through every record in the log table, I presume there must be a way of extracting this data using a SQL query?

For example, my data looks like this:

| ID | TYPE | POINT | RFID | LOGGED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 4101 | 1234 | 2021-01-20 06:31:25:154 |
| 2 | 101 | 4101 | 4567 | 2021-01-20 06:32:24:165 |
| 3 | 101 | 4102 | 1234 | 2021-01-20 06:35:55:154 |
| 4 | 101 | 4102 | 1234 | 2021-01-20 06:35:55:516 |

What I want to do is identify where I have duplicate RFID records where the POINT is the same and the time difference between the records is less than 5 seconds.

In the example above, IDs 3 & 4 would be returned as duplicate because they are both from POINT 4102, have the same RFID and the LOGGED difference is less than 5 seconds.

Although ID 1 has the same RFID (1234) as ID 3 & 4, this would not be a duplicate because the POINT is different.

I tried to write a query to return the duplicates, but I get no results, even though I have found some by looking through the table:

```
DECLARE @TheDate date
SET @TheDate = '2021-01-20'

SELECT 
    [Type]
    ,[Point]
    ,[RFID]
    ,[Logged]
FROM 
    [Log]
WHERE 
    @TheDate = CONVERT(date,[Logged])
    AND [Point] IN ('4101', '4102')
    AND [Type] = '101'
GROUP BY 
    [Type], [Point], [RFID], [Logged]
HAVING 
    COUNT([RFID]) > 1
```

The other problem I have is that I have no idea how to do the datetime comparison to see if the difference in time is less than 5 seconds.

Comment: . . I added the SQL Server tag based on the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`.  For all such rows:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             lag(logged) over (partition by rfid order by logged) as prev_logged,
             lead(logged) over (partition by rfid order by logged) as next_logged
      from logs l
     ) l
where prev_logged > dateadd(second, -5, logged) or
      next_logged < dateadd(second, 5, logged);
```

Your sample code looks like SQL Server so this uses SQL Server syntax.

If you just want the first record in a sequence of duplicates, you can use similar logic:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             lag(logged) over (partition by rfid order by logged) as prev_logged,
             lead(logged) over (partition by rfid order by logged) as next_logged
      from logs l
     ) l
where (prev_logged < dateadd(second, -5, logged) or prev_logged is null) and
      next_logged < dateadd(second, 5, logged);
```

Note that both of these only use the `rfid`.  I'm not sure if the `rfid` should really be used in conjunction with other columns, such as `point`, but your question explicitly mentioned only duplicate `rfid`.